# woocommerce - how to get product link by id

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, categories

i have 2 product_cat

`Product cat 1` id : 6

`Product cat 2` id : 8

in my index how to get product cat link with id or slug as:

`<a href="Product cat 1 (link)">Product cat 1(name)</a>`

`<a href="Product cat 2 (link)">Product cat 2(name)</a>`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product category is just a regular wordpress taxonomy. You can get the link like this:

```
echo esc_url( get_term_link( 6, 'product_cat' ) );
```

You can use slugs too:

```
echo esc_url( get_term_link( 'category-slug', 'product_cat' ) );
```